# Can't compile boost

Tags: c++, boost

I have some problems with boost_1_55_0.
I've got this error when 
`#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>`

```
 In file included from ../../Tools/boost_1_55_0/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:167:0,
                 from ../../Client/RequestManager/Request/AsyncCheckAndUpdateCharacterInventoryRequest.cpp:12:
../../Tools/boost_1_55_0/boost/math/special_functions/sign.hpp:115:68: error: macro "method" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
    return detail::signbit_impl(static_cast<result_type>(x), method());
```

Compiling on Linux. g++-4.8.2
This code compiling with old boost(1_46_1), but I have some linker errors with libboost_filesystem.a, because no old version of libbost in Ubuntu repos

Comment: How does your code look like that doesn't compile? You are using a boost macro wrong.

Comment: Do you have a macro called "method" defined somewhere? If not, what header files are included before lexical_cast.hpp?

Comment: Before lexical_cast.hpp included boost/bind.hpp. This code compiling with old boost(1_46_1)

Comment: @mut Is that the only thing? Other boost headers should be no problem. That it was compiling with an older boost version is important information. I suggest to add it to the question.

Comment: @Samuel more output: `In file included from ../../Tools/boost_1_55_0/boost/lexical_cast.hpp:167:0,
                 from ../../Client/RequestManager/Request/AsyncCheckAndUpdateCharacterInventoryRequest.cpp:12:
../../Tools/boost_1_55_0/boost/math/special_functions/sign.hpp:115:68: error: macro "method" requires 2 arguments, but only 1 given
    return detail::signbit_impl(static_cast<result_type>(x), method());`

Comment: This is not getting better. Update your post and show me your code where you *USE* something from boost.

Comment: @mut Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the usage is the inclusion of boost/lexical_cast.hpp at AsyncCheckAndUpdateCharacterInventoryRequest‌​.cpp:12.

Comment: @mwijns yeap, you are right. erros not in usage, error when including

Comment: Can you do search in your codebase for "method"? I still think there is some interfering define somewhere. The code in boost that is triggering the problem was added between 1_46_1 and 1_55_0.